# bug in wp-pagenavi plugin

Tags: wordpress

I have downloaded the wp-pagenavi from this location. `http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-pagenavi/installation/`. I am using wordpress 3.3.1. I have installed this plugin using the instructions. I used the following code in home.php to display the posts and pagination.

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Home Page
 */
get_header(); 


?>

<?php include(TEMPLATEPATH."/sidebar.php");?>

    <div id="content_right">
    <?php if ( function_exists('yoast_breadcrumb') ) {
    yoast_breadcrumb('<div id="breadcrumbs">','</div>');
} ?>
<div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
<?php 
// Display most recent posts

$the_query = new WP_Query( "showposts=5" );
$postcount = 0;
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
$postcount++;
 ?>

<div class="blog_left">
<div><?php
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
  the_post_thumbnail();
} 
?>

</div>
</div>
<div class="blog_right">
<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<div>in: <?php the_category(', ') ?></div>
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
</div>
 <div class="clear"></div>

<?php
if( $postcount != 5){?> 
 <p class="blogdivider"></p>

<?php } ?>

<?php endwhile; 
$count = 0;
?>
<?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>

    </div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

But pagination doesn't display in my webpage. I couldn't track what is missing. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
        <?php

$paged = intval(get_query_var('paged'));

if($paged == 0) {

$paged = 1;

}

?>
```

or

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( "showposts=5,get_query_var=paged" );
```

Answer (score 0):

This form works:

```
 //if not exists assigns value 1
 $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; 

 //query 5 posts
 query_posts("posts_per_page=5&paged=$paged");
```

Comment: Be careful when posting copy and paste boilerplate/verbatim answers to multiple questions, these tend to be flagged as "spammy" by the community. If you're doing this then it usually means the questions are duplicates so flag them as such instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518478/wp-pagenavi-not-working-solution/9571088#9571088