# wp_pagenavi not working (solution)

Tags: wordpress, plugins

Had a minor problem with this neat plugin and solved it. It is said that wp_pagenavi does not work with eg. WP_query().
This should be also noted with **get_posts()**, did not see anything from this plugin. When changed to **query_posts()** then navi plugin started to work again.

Answer (score 0):

This form works:

```
 //if not exists assigns value 1
 $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; 

 //query 5 posts
 query_posts("posts_per_page=5&paged=$paged");
```

Comment: Yeah but this is still in query_posts(); Had problem width get_posts() :)